# Slide toggle doesn't apply when element is initially hidden?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following html snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/foo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="apdu layer">
  <div class="apdu layer entry">APDU</div>

    <div class="hci layer">
    <div class="hci layer entry">HCI</div>

        <div class="raw layer">
          <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>            
          <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>            
          <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>            
    </div>

    </div>

  <div class="hci layer">
    <div class="hci layer entry">HCI</div>

    <div class="raw layer">
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="hci layer">
    <div class="hci layer entry">HCI</div>
    <div class="raw layer">
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
      <div class="raw layer entry">RAW</div>        
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

with the following javascript

```
$(function()
{   
$('.apdu.layer.entry').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.hci.layer').slideToggle();
});

$('.hci.layer.entry').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.raw.layer').slideToggle();
});

});
```

works all great and expected.

However, when I add the following two lines to initially hide the two div(s)

```
$('.hci.layer').hide();
$('.raw.layer').hide();
```

there is a 'rough animation' that looks like the sliding takes place, but the contents remain hidden.

From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) of slideToggle()

> If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

Comment: Created jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QEkwz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding the children *and their* children (and so on, it matches any div with those classes), if you want to re-show them, you need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (which would only toggle the *immediate* children), like this:

```
$(function() {   
    $('.hci.layer, .raw.layer').hide();
    $('.apdu.layer.entry').click( function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.hci.layer').slideToggle();
    });        
    $('.hci.layer.entry').click( function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.raw.layer').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SDtkT/)

---

However, a smoother approach would be to just not hide the `.entry` divs, using the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), like this:

```
$('.hci.layer:not(.entry), .raw.layer:not(.entry)').hide();
```

Then use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of `.parent().children()`, like this:

```
$(function() {   
    $('.hci.layer:not(.entry), .raw.layer:not(.entry)').hide();
    $('.apdu.layer.entry').click( function() {
        $(this).siblings('.hci.layer').slideToggle();
    });        
    $('.hci.layer.entry').click( function() {
        $(this).siblings('.raw.layer').slideToggle();
    });
});
​
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SDtkT/1/), you can see the animation is much smoother now that you're only hiding/showing what you need at each level.

Comment: Working response and excellent insight as well as to how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not the best solution, but if you call

```
$('.hci.layer.entry').click();
$('.apdu.layer.entry').click();
```

instead of

```
$('.hci.layer').hide();
$('.raw.layer').hide();
```

to initially *hide* the divs, it works.